# Cookie session Firefox

Tags: wget, authentication, cookies, browser-cache, session

WGET need some cookies (because he like those, but not only), because some files are only accessible while authenticated. But i find nowhere how to get these cookies (and i can't autenticate from WGET considering that the authentification procedure is not suported by WGET)

I use Firefox but do not hesitate to post solutions for any browser/software for the other users

Comment: Have a look - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324421/how-to-get-past-the-login-page-with-wget

Comment: I come from this question, I created this question because this question doesn't explain how to get cookies